# File not sending using cron

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

I am trying to send a file to a server using cron for scheduling function but when my php script is run by cron, the script for sending file is not working but when I run it manually (both in browser and terminal) it works just fine. I don't know what's the problem. I also have an insert into query after that code and it works when cron runs my php script.

here's my php script:

```
for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($id); $x++){

//check account
$xml_str="<request type='UPLOAD_CONTENT' username='user' password='".md5('pass')."' identification=''>
<content contenttype='NORMAL' caption='$playlistname' md5='".md5_file($packagename)."' terminalidlist='".$id[$x]."' downloaddatetype='ANYDATE' downloadtimetype='ANYTIME'/>
</request>";
$url = "http://localhost:8080/CommitLoginAction.do" . urlencode($xml_str);
$response = `curl -F file=@$packagename $url`;
echo($response);
$data = simplexml_load_string($response);

print_r($response);
}
?>
```

here's my cron:

```
 */05 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/dlti/scheduler.php
```

Comment: Are you certain that the scripts is run with cron at all? And maybe you should point absolutely to the curl binary?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the error logs? Also, do you have any includes on the php script, or is this the full script?

Comment: It is possible that the user under which this script is executed by cron (if it is executed) does not have some permissions.

Comment: @Repox Yes, I am sure. I checked the log and it says it was run by cron and like what I mentioned earlier, the mysql query inside the php script was able to run.

Comment: @Rik_S I tried to run the script in terminal to look for errors(php scheduler.php) and it sends without a problem..

Comment: @Cheery I am using only 1 user when executing it by cron and by ubuntu. :\

Comment: @tengcy Is the script including any other scripts?

Comment: @Rik_S nope, just the mysql queries(which run perfectly).

Comment: Have a look at the "debugging" section of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info

Comment: Ubuntu has more than 1 user in it. Check permissions.

Comment: @Cheery but the script is already running, only 1 part of the script doesn't work.